# Mobile Alternative to multiselect combobox?

Tags: forms, mobile

I am currently using an html form with a multiple select drop down list box.

This doesn't work well on mobile so I am looking for options on what I could use an alternative component?

Currently I have:

```
<form method="post" action="/submit.php" id="countries_multi_select">
<select id="countries" name="countries[]" multiple="multiple">
<option>France</option>
<option>Germany</option>
<option>Portugal</option>
<option>Spain</option>
<option>UK</option>
<option>etc</option>
</select>
```

Submit

The shift click is a problem for a touch screen, so I am looking for something better.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what i am looking for here:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/forms/multiselect/